# Find/Move/Delete Objects by Key in Complex JSON Structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures

*"Help me, StackOverflow. You're my last hope!"*

Im trying to build a small application which main purpose is to generate React Components out of a JSON Structure, moving those components around (Drag and Drop), deleting them, adding new... and so on.

My data structure looks like this:

```
    data: [
    {
        type: enums.ROW,
        id: 0,
        children: [
            {
                type: enums.COL,
                id: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        type: enums.TEXTBLOCK,
                        id: 2,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: enums.COL,
                id: 3,
                children: [
                    {
                        type: enums.TEXTBLOCK,
                        id: 4,
                        innerHTML: "Text II"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: enums.COL,
                id: 5,
                children: [
                    {
                        type: enums.TEXTBLOCK,
                        id: 6,
                        innerHTML: "Text III"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I'm stuck at those kinda like CRUD Operations.
I need to get a node based on its ID. I need to add/move them to other nodes (those that have the children property).

I don't know where I should start to solve this problem. Already tried some basic recursive functions, looping through every element in data[] and if that element has the children property, then loop through every item of that until it finds the element with the given id, but none of that works exactly like I want it to.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Didn't fully understand your problem. Can you provide some examples ? How will you move nodes etc.

Comment: The structure as seen in my post will generate the following: [link](http://i.epvpimg.com/MdJLfab.png). Now I want to move a column into another column (drag and drop). It would look like this: [link](http://i.epvpimg.com/VpbUeab.png) and that would be the structure of the target: [link](http://i.epvpimg.com/JAKYeab.png)

Hope I could make this clear :s